# cakephp more query in a page

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-model

I have a question, if in my page I want to search:
- Last 10 registered users
- Last 10 login users 
- Last 10 users that have inserted a product

These query are more than one, well in my controller I have to make more query  and every query put it into a variable right?

something like that?

```
$first_query = $this->User->find ('all', array(
                    'conditions' => array(...)
            )); 
$second_query = $this->User->find ('all', array(
                    'conditions' => array(...)
            )); 
$third_query = $this->User->find ('all', array(
                    'conditions' => array(...)
            ));
```

And in my view I'll use the variables `$first_query`, `$second_query`, `$third_query`

Is correct or is better to divide into more function on the controller the query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the way you do it is "the" way. You should probably name them differently, though, since the variables do not contain any queries, but results, and "first", "second" etc. says nothing about the content. I'd call them `$lastRegisteredUsers`, `$lastLoggedInUsers`etc.

If the conditions are very similar, like if you want to select users from only one category, or some such, you could store that condition in a variable and reuse it, instead of copy-pasting.

Comment: Sure the names will be different, the conditions are not similar unfortunately... Thanks I take this way!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code in your controller's action method:
You can map the model association with itself. And this will return you the expected result.

```
$this->User->bindModel(array('belongsTo' => array('LastRegUser' => 
                                                                  array(
                                                                        'className' => 'User',
                                                                        'foreignKey' => 'id',
                                                                        'conditions' => array(...)),
                                                  'LoggedInUser' => array(
                                                                        'className' => 'User',
                                                                        'foreignKey' => 'id',
                                                                        'conditions' => array(...)) ..... )));
```

And then you can simple use the following code to fetch all the users using following code.

```
$users = $this->User->find('all');
```